# CloudTable ExecuteQuery async

Tags: c#, azure, asynchronous, azure-table-storage

Is it possible to run ExecuteQuery asynchronously?

Consider the following code:

```
public virtual MyEntity MyMethod(string parm1, string parm2)
{
     string queryString = TableQuery.CombineFilters(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, parm1),
                                                    TableOperators.And,
                                                    TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("RowKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, parm2));
     TableQuery<MyEntity> query = new TableQuery<MyEntity>().Where(queryString);

     return TenantTnsTable.ExecuteQuery(query).ToList().FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Is it possible to make this a async method and use await on the ExecuteQuery call?

Comment: https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/266

Answer (score 0):

Try `Task.Run`. You should be able to run any non-async code asynchronously and then `await` the result.

Comment: This isn't proper asynchrony though, it's async over sync.  Here it'd be better to just leave the synchronous method and let the caller wrap it in a call to `Run` if they need it to be done in a background thread, but allowing them to avoid that overhead if they don't in fact need it.

Comment: Better to use Task.FromResult

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap old style call backs with Task.Factory.FromAsync. Eg:

```
public static Task<TableQuerySegment<T>> ExecuteQueryAsync<T>(
        this CloudTable table,
        TableQuery<T> query,
        TableContinuationToken token,
        CancellationToken ct = default(CancellationToken))
        where T : ITableEntity, new()
    {
        ICancellableAsyncResult ar = table.BeginExecuteQuerySegmented(query, token, null, null);
        ct.Register(ar.Cancel);

        return Task.Factory.FromAsync<TableQuerySegment<T>>(ar, table.EndExecuteQuerySegmented<T>);
    }
```